# Posting questions to groups via the graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to the Facebook graph API and I am currently developing my first app using the php-sdk. I am looking to be able to post questions on a group via the graph API. I have come across Facebook's blog post here http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/ which gives an example of posting a question to a page, but I have found little documentation on posting questions to groups. I have attempted to post a question to a group with the following code, which is throwing an 'Unsupported post request' error. I don’t know why it isn’t working, as I have no problems posting questions to a users feed with this code.

```
$params = array(
    'question'=> $question,
    'options'=> $options,
    'allow_new_options' => false  
);

$questionpost = $facebook->api('/' . $ID . '/questions', 'POST', $params);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is odd.  You cannot (as well as I cannot) find documentation on how to post a question to a group via the API.  Then you try posting a question, just like you can to a page (per the blog post), to a group and receive an error.  Well, I assume that pretty well confirms that you *cannot* post a question to a group using the API.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/

> We are now adding the option to write them. To create a question for
>   the current user, issue an HTTP POST to the questions connection like
>   this:
>
> Here's a PHP example that shows the optional parameters: options and
>   allow_new_options -- and how to post a question as a Page using its
>   access token:

Please notice they did not say you can do this for groups.  Only users and pages.

You should file a bug with Facebook asking them to implement the ability to post a question to a group.  Please report back here the bug number so other stack overflow users can see/track the bug.

Thanks!

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have filed a bug with Facebook, the bug number is 364789483545929.